# Why do all standard commands include an ASCII letter?

Tags: filenames, executable, unicode

Although one can easily make an executable file named `./42` or even `./カラオケ`, I find no common packages that include letter-free commands.  On Ubuntu, for example, `apt-file find . | grep -i -e '/[^a-z/_\-]+$'` reports that every executable file's basename has at least a letter or underscore or dash.  The only letter-free files or dirs that I found were non-executable, and usually version numbers: `docbook/dtd/xml/4.1.2`, `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2`, etc.

Do any published rules or standards constrain how commands may be named?  Or is this merely cultural practice?

Comment: Short of an answer, but the [POSIX spec for path names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271) says: ... "If a pathname consists of only bytes corresponding to characters from the portable filename character set (see Portable Filename Character Set), <slash> characters, and a single terminating <NUL> character, the pathname will be usable as a character string in all supported locales" ...

Comment: So the P.F.C.S. is letters, digits, dot, dash, and underscore.  At least that rules out katakana, cyrillic, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample: the `[` command, the one you use when you write `if [ "$foo" = bar ]`. It's the same as `test`, except that it requires the final `]` argument, and is [a standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Yes, it's an executable file:

```
# ls -l "/usr/bin/["
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 51920 Mar  2  2017 /usr/bin/[
```

Comment: Doh!  (Then I'm confused why `apt-file find /usr/bin/\[` finds it, but `apt-file find .` doesn't.  usr/bin/[ *is* in security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_Contents-amd64.gz;  maybe instead I should've done zcat | grep.)